# Using a function with deferred.done()

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I have the following function:

```
function checkTag(dataVal) {
    return $.ajax({
        data: {input: dataVal}
        ...
    });
}
```

Currently, on keyup, that function is called as such:

```
$("#element").on("keyup", function() {
    var tag = $(this).val();
    checkTag(tag).done(function(data) {
        ...
    });
});
```

and that works without an issue. However, later in my code, I want to call that `deferred.done()` again. I've therefore created a function as such:

```
function checkTagDone(data) {
    ...
}
```

And tried to call it like this:

```
checkTag(tag).done(checkTagDone(data));
```

and also tried:

```
$.when(checkTag(tag)).done(checkTagDone(data));
```

but in both instances I get `variable 'data' is not found` at console. I've clearly misunderstood the usage of `deferred.done` however there must be a way of iterating over the same `deferred.done` without having to replicate the code. I can find documentation to support multiple `deferred.done` instances following a single AJAX call, but nowhere can I find a solution to replicate the same `deferred.done` following multiple AJAX calls.

Relevant jQuery for `object htmlinputelement` issue:

```
function checkTagDone(data, tag) {    
    if (data) {
        ...
        //Create span around tag input
        $(".tree").last().append("<span class='tag'>"+tag+"</span>").fadeIn(500).val("");
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the function reference to `done` like and pass the value of the `tag` to the `checkTag` method(Because from what I can see `tag` is a local variable in the `keyup` scope.).

```
checkTag($("#element").val()).done(checkTagDone);
```

---

```
var tag = $("#element").val();
checkTag(tag).done(function (data) {
    checkTagDone(data, tag);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried it, but then instead of the value being returned I get `object htmlinputelement`??

Comment: @Ryan in which method

Comment: In `checkTagDone`. I do refer to `tag` in my `checkTagDone` method, so presumably replacing `tag` in `checkTag` with the selector itself as you've suggested is causing the issue as that reference is now no longer valid??

Answer (score 0):

Ryan, you appear to have two choices :

**Leave the event handler as it is, and trigger the keyup event to re-perform ajax on the element's current value**

```
$("#element").trigger('keyup');
```

This can be performed at any point in your code. There are no scope issues as all code has access to the DOM.

**Modify the event handler such that it saves the most recent ajax promise in an outer scope**

```
var lastKeyupPromise;
...
$("#element").on('keyup', function() {
    lastKeyupPromise = checkTag($(this).val()).done(checkTagDone);
});
```

Then, elsewhere in your code :

```
if(lastKeyupPromise) { // safety is required as `lastKeyupPromise` may still be undefined
    lastKeyupPromise.done(checkTagDone);
}
```

This can be performed at any point in your code providing `lastKeyupPromise` and `checkTagDone` are in scope.

The advantages of the second aproach are :

- No need to perform another ajax request.
- You are not limited to executing `checkTagDone`. You can choose to execute whatever is appropriate at that point in your code.

For example :

```
if(lastKeyupPromise) {
    lastKeyupPromise.done(someOtherHandler);
}
```